# Apache Superset : bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, apache-superset

I created a new environment to run a superset dashboard, `super_dash`, I get an error `bad interpreter: No such file or directory` when I run it.Not able to do any activities.

I tried

1. To reinstall `pip install apache-superset', but the results seems to be same.
2. Install `pip install apache-superset' in a different environment, the result is still the same.

However when I run superset in my base environment there is no issue.

Please find the environment details

```
(super_dash) hashi-MacBook-Air:~ hashi$ which python
/Users/hashi/DG/env/super_dash/bin/python


(super_dash) hashi-MacBook-Air:~ hashi$ which python3
/Users/hashi/DG/env/super_dash/bin/python3


(super_dash) hashi-MacBook-Air:~ hashi$ which pip
/Users/hashi/DG/env/super_dash/bin/pip
```

Base version

```
(base) hashi-MacBook-Air:~ hashi$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

(base) hashi-MacBook-Air:~ hashi$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

(base) hashi-MacBook-Air:~ hashi$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

Mac : macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Several issues available in the net

1. Wrong pointing of Python version
2. Issue with improper pip version / linkage

I basically understand from all these is that issue with the way python was installed.

Tried many solutions with no result.

Can anyone give me more clarity on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the issue.
Root Cause : Multiple Python Versions

Solution :

install : 'python3 -m pip install apache-superset'

instead of `superset run -p 8088`
run        `python3 superset run -p 8088`